# Routh Table First Column 0: Total number of RHP poles

Tags: polynomials, roots, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, characteristic-polynomial

I was doing some research and found that when a first column 0 appears but everything else is not necessarily 0 in the row, then there exists poles with nonnegative real parts (or positive real parts if there are no imaginary roots or “opposite” roots in general). From what I saw, the proof mentions the *existence* of non-LHP poles, but doesn’t provide proof of **number** of non-LHP poles based on the first column 0 (actually, I saw one, but it doesn’t give a “hard” proof).

Based on my observations, if a first zero appears in row $s^m$, at least 2 Routh rows can be skipped including $s^m$, depending on how many consecutive zeros appear after the first zero. For example, if there’s a nonzero value after the first zero, then we go to $s^{m-2}$ and consider the sign change between $s^{m+1}$ and $s^{m-2}$. Likewise, if there are two consecutive zeros including the first row zero, then we consider the sign change between $s^{m+1}$ and $s^{m-4}$ (the rows in between are skipped). We see that the *total* number of rows skipped due to the first column zeros is an even number (let’s denote this as $2b$). Is there a way to prove that there is a relationship between the number of skipped rows due to first column zeros and the total number of non-LHP poles (or RHP poles if there aren’t any imaginary poles)? In other words, is there a way to prove the relationship between $P$ (total number of RHP poles), $b$, and $V\left(\infty\right)$, where $V\left(\infty\right)$ is the number of sign changes of the Sturm polynomial sequence at $\infty$ (or the number of sign changes in the Routh table)? Also, can one provide a reference to the source like an article or a journal? I have a “proof”, but it’s incorrect, because I am somehow mixing up $P$ as the *total* number of RHP poles and the number of RHP poles captured from the shortened Routh table.

I ask because the epsilon method can get one into a very hairy situation like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3381108/750070) or even provide misleading results like the one mentioned by F.R. Gantmacher in *The Theory of Matrices, Volume 2*, page 184.

Worked “example”, using the notation from Routh and Gantmacher:
$$F\left(s\right) = s^4 + s^3 + 2s^2 + 2s + 1.$$

Using the small parameter method, we see that there are two RHP poles. Without it, I get

$$V\left(\infty\right) + V\left(-\infty\right) = n - 2b = N + P - 2b = 2,$$

where $n$ is the polynomial degree, $N$ the number of LHP poles, and $V\left(-\infty\right)$ the number of sign changes of the Sturm polynomial sequence at $-\infty$. Here, $b = 1$. By the definition of the Cauchy index,

$$V\left(-\infty\right) - V\left(\infty\right) = N - P.$$

Using my previous worked relationship between the $V$’s and $N$, $P$, and $b$, I get

$$V\left(-\infty\right) = N - b = 2 \rightarrow N = 3,$$

and

$$ V\left(\infty\right) = P - b = 0 \rightarrow P = 1,$$

which contradicts with the correct answer.